# Problema en insertar un dato a una tabla de SQLserver

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Este es mi codigo, sin la fecha, todo me funciona normal, inserta los datos, pero colocando la fecha, mediante el JSON me lanza este error (The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK__Reclamos__rut_us__619B8048\". The conflict occurred in database \"SistemaReclamos\", table \"dbo.Usuario\", column 'rut'."). Estoy desde el IDE, haciendo los insert y mediante Swagger UI para introducir el JSON

```
 static public int insertarReclamo(Reclamos reclamos) throws Exception, SQLException {
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = Conexion.obtenerConexion();
    }
    String insert = "insert into Reclamos(tipo_problema, texto_reclamo, fecha, rut_usuario) values (?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert);

    ps.setString(1, reclamos.getTipo_problema());
    ps.setString(2, reclamos.getTexto_reclamo());
    ps.setInt(4, reclamos.getRut_usuario());
    ps.setString(3, reclamos.getFecha());
    int resultado = ps.executeUpdate();
    return resultado;
}
```

Este seria mi controlador

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/insertarReclamo")
public void insertarReclamo(@RequestBody Reclamos reclamos) throws Exception {
   ReclamosDAO.insertarReclamo(reclamos);
}
```

Y estos son mis atributos,constructor, getter y setter.

```
public class Reclamos {
private int rut_usuario;
private int num_reclamo;
private String tipo_problema;
private String texto_reclamo;
private String fecha;


public Reclamos(int rut_usuario, int num_reclamo, String tipo_problema, String texto_reclamo, String fecha) {
    this.num_reclamo = num_reclamo;
    this.tipo_problema = tipo_problema;
    this.texto_reclamo = texto_reclamo;
    this.rut_usuario = rut_usuario;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public int getRut_usuario() {
    return rut_usuario;
}

public void setRut_usuario(int rut_usuario) {
    this.rut_usuario = rut_usuario;
}

public String getTipo_problema() {
    return tipo_problema;
}

public void setTipo_problema(String tipo_problema) {
    this.tipo_problema = tipo_problema;
}


public String getTexto_reclamo() {
    return texto_reclamo;
}

public int getNum_reclamo() {
    return num_reclamo;
}

public void setNum_reclamo(int num_reclamo) {
    this.num_reclamo = num_reclamo;
}

public void setTexto_reclamo(String texto_reclamo) {
    this.texto_reclamo = texto_reclamo;
}
```

}

Esto lo manda el SWAGGER UI

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-05-02T19:04:29.045+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK__Reclamos__rut_us__619B8048\". The conflict occurred in database \"SistemaReclamos\", table \"dbo.Usuario\", column 'rut'.",
  "path": "/api/insertarReclamo"
}
```

Esta es mi base de datos

```
create table Usuario(
rut int NOT NULL primary key,
nombre varchar(50),
apellido varchar(50),
telefono int,
correo varchar(50),
direccion varchar (100),
contraseña varchar(50),
producto varchar (250) null,
cargo varchar (100) null,
permiso varchar(10) null
)
drop table Usuario

create table SLA(
tipo_reclamo varchar(50) NOT NULL primary key,
SLA_reclamo varchar(50)
)

create table Reclamos(
num_reclamo int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
rut_usuario int foreign key references Usuario (rut),
tipo_problema varchar(50),
fecha varchar(50),
texto_reclamo varchar(max),
estado varchar (50),
SLA_reclamo varchar(50)
)
drop table Reclamos

create table Respuesta(
num_reclamo int NOT NULL foreign key references Reclamos (num_reclamo) primary key,
rut_admin int NOT NULL foreign key references Usuario(rut),
texto_respuesta varchar(max),
fecha_respuesta varchar(50),
SLA_respuesta varchar(50)
)

drop table Respuesta
}
```

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, por favor las respuestas si pueden ser especificas, por favor.
Gracias de antemano :D

Comment: Te dice que tenes un error con una Foreign key, tenes que fijarte las relaciones de tu base de datos, si te falta algun dato de pasarle en la tabla y existe el mismo en la otra.

Comment: Hola, ahi publique mi base de datos

Comment: estas borrando las tablas, despues de crearlas

Comment: No, o sea, eso lo tengo ahi por emergencia, no ejecuto, efectivamente las tengo creadas y le añadi unos valores, de hecho, cuando desde el IDE no le mandaba el parametro de FECHA, todo funcionaba, pero necesito enviarle ese parametro, por eso no quiero solo borrarlo :C

Comment: Todo indicate que te falta o tener el usuario ingresado en tu base de datos, o ese usuario no lo estas pasando en la insercion.

Comment: Muchas graciaaas, verifique, era eso, estaba pasando el json sin un RUT que estuviera registrado en la base de datos, muchas gracias de verdad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, por favor las respuestas si
>   pueden ser especificas, por favor.

El error te indica que lo que insertas no existe en la tabla de usuarios.

Ejecuto las sentencia de creación de todas tus tablas en *mi base de datos*.

Con la misma, lo primero que hago es ejecutar la inserción que tu haces.

```
insert into Reclamos(tipo_problema, texto_reclamo, fecha, rut_usuario) 
values ('mitexto','texto','fecha es un string por tanto 010101',1);
```

Esto me resuelve el mismo error.

```
Mens. 547, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 1
Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY 'FK__Reclamos__rut_us__3864608B'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'Lab1', tabla 'dbo.Usuario', column 'rut'.
Se terminó la instrucción.
```

Porque la tabla reclamos en su columna rut_usuario dice que todo registro que esté aquí tiene que existir en Usuario por su columna rut.

> rut_usuario int foreign key references Usuario (rut),

Ahora procedo a insertar el usuario 1 en la tabla de usuarios.

```
Insert into Usuario(rut)
values
(1);
```

No es obligatorio que defina más columnas para este ejemplo, porque todas permiten valores null, excepto rut que es la clave primaria.

Y vuelvo a ejecutar la misma sentencia de antes.

```
insert into Reclamos(tipo_problema, texto_reclamo, fecha, rut_usuario) 
values ('mitexto','texto','fecha es un string por tanto 010101',1);
```

Ahora el resultado de la inserción es correcto, ya que reclamos.rut_usuario=1 y existe un registro en usuario cuya columna rut=1;